# extracting all files in tar to a remote server

Tags: tar

The command below extracts the specified file in a remote machine:

```
tar -xzOf file.tar.gz file_you_want_to_extract | ssh user@host 'cat > /path/to/destination_file'
```

My requirement is that I want to extract all the files in to the remote machine. How can i achieve this ?

```
tar -xzOf file.tar.gz | ssh user@host 'cat > /path_dir'
```

All the files in file.tar.gz should be extracted in the remote host in /path_dir .

Answer (score 8):

```
cat myfile.tgz | ssh user@host "tar xzf - -C /some/dir"
```

Comment: Even better than the verbose file listing `cat myfile.tgz | ssh user@host "tar xvzf - -C /some/dir"` is the [tag:pv] progress bar! `pv myfile.tgz | ssh user@host "tar xzf - -C /some/dir"`